# Searching object from ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, collections

```
List <obj> list1= new ArrayList<obj>();

obj a1 = new obj("value11", value21);
obj a2 = new obj("value12", value22);
obj a3 = new obj("value11", value23);

list1.add(a1);
list1.add(a2);
list1.add(a3);
```

Now i need to get the objects in Array list whoes value is "value11".

Expected objects are a1 and a3

Comment: simply iterate over it and check your condition and return. Whats the hurdle?

Comment: can you show your obj class?

Answer (score 0):

use this line
System.out.println(list1);

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expression:

```
List<obj> result = list1.stream()
.filter(p -> p.someProperty == "value11").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of filtering an ArrayList:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("A");
    items.add("B");
    items.add("C");
    items.add("D");
    items.add("E");

items.stream()
        .filter(s->s.contains("D"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[Java ArrayList Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

User lambda expression like this:

```
List <obj> list1= new ArrayList<obj>();

obj a1 = new obj("value11", value21);
obj a2 = new obj("value12", value22);
obj a3 = new obj("value11", value23);

list1.add(a1);
list1.add(a2);
list1.add(a3);
```

let's assume our obj class is something like this

```
public class obj  
{
 public String item_key {get;set;}
 public String item_value {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can find something like this:

```
var i = list1.where(model=>model.item_key.equal("value11"));
```

This will return all the item contains "value11"